# Spring Boot 3.1.5 Spring securityFilterChain config failed

Tags: spring-security

I try config Spring Security, When I access an api that does not exist, it responds with 403 or automatically redirects.But I configured filtering this path, but it doesn't seem to take effect.

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/home", "/test").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                        .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                        .failureHandler((request, response, exception) -> {
                            logger.debug("securityFilterChain login failed!");
                            logger.debug("securityFilterChain login failed exception : " + exception.getStackTrace());
                            ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse.error().message("login failed");
                            writeApiResponse(response, apiResponse);
                        })
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll())
                .csrf(crsf -> crsf.disable());
        return http.build();
    }
```

As configured in the above code, the path 'test' has a corresponding controller, but 'home' does not. When requesting test, the response is normal, which means that the filter is effective, but accessing home is not a normal response 404.

Comment: Enable DEBUG logs and edit your question to include the full debug logs